# Wordpress: I need every blog posts to appear under the Blog Page, AND the latest post to appear in a Category (code not working thus far)

Tags: wordpress, function

I have been trying to have one specific page display all the posts, while having a Category display only the latest post. Both my Page and Category appear as part of the main menu.

This piece of code in the functions.php will display a single post for both my Page and my Category. However, I need the Blog Page to show all of them. While only a single post for the Category. (I cannot use plugins, as they want this to be done by hand).

```
 if( is_page_template( 'article-vedette-solo.php' ) ){

    function my_main_query($query){
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','my_main_query');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pre_get_posts` have different priority level, you can not put that action to another if condition.

Try in other way, put your 1st condition inside the `pre_get_posts` action, it may help you. Find the code below,

```
function my_main_query($query) {

    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        if( is_page_template( 'article-vedette-solo.php' ) ) {

            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','my_main_query');
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I see the difference in terms of how your code works (which makes more sense than mine). However, I wasn't able to get it to work. I played around with it and tried a few things, but it still hasn't worked. I also removed the _template (unless I am mistaking, I should simply use is_page).

EDIT: Maybe I am not correctly using the article-vedette-solo.php? Am I erroneously believing that WP would create that specific page?

Comment: bdw i am still confused with requirement. What I understand, you have a blog page that's all fine, and you need to display the single latest post from that particular category when that category page is called. Am i right ?

Comment: Not quite. Both the "Category" and the "Page" calls the written posts from the section called "Posts", which are created by the user -  this is the option beneath the Dashboard. 

The "Category" itself will have the latest post (only one post), while the "Page" itself will have all the posts.

I was wrong thinking it created a php page, and so now I am even more confused as to how I can accomplish my goal.